# jQuery .load requesting unwanted images

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404

I have 2 websites.  Site A's home page contains a news section and I have used jQuery's .load function to load this content into a div on a page in Site B using the following code:

```
$('.siteBnews').load('http://www.sitea.co.uk .news');
```

This all works fine. The problem is that after the content is pulled in, every single image on the source page is then requested, none of which are in the .news section. The browser console is littered with 404 errors because the requested URLs are in the format http://siteb.sitea.co.uk/image.jpg.

I can see no reason why it would be attempting to grab all these images and although this doesn't affect the page as such, I'd rather not have a load of 404 errors occurring. Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: try shwoing it in a Iframe

Comment: I try to open the given link but it returns an the error below: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: I would imagine that jQuery takes the html and creates a DOM element in memory from it so that it can parse through the elements to find elements which match ".news". Does it still do this if you don't specify a selector?

Comment: @Robert_Junior I only want to display a small section of the page so I can't use an iframe.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina That's not a real link, just an example of the format.

Comment: @DominicTobias Yep, does the same thing without specifying a selector.

Comment: Standard way is to use a webservice from site A which returns news in json format

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that there is no way of doing this with `.load` because in the success callback it is adding the responseText to a node:

```
self.html( selector ?

    // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
    // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
    jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :

    // Otherwise use the full result
    responseText );
```

which is creating DOM elements in memory. If you for example clear your network tab and do in your console:

```
$('<img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>')
```

You will see the image being loaded in the network tab because the browser loads images even if they are inserted into the DOM (this is how & why image pre-loaders work). You will probably have to use `$.ajax` or `$.get` (which is what load is using under the hood) and manually parse through the returned HTML string, and only wrap the element you want into a jQuery object. Parsing through html can be a pain, this is why jQuery is doing this through a DOM element instead.

e.g `$.get({ url: 'http://www.sitea.co.uk', dataType: 'html'}).done(..parse data string..)`